# Getting current state of MediaPlayer in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I have made a music player using the MediaPlayer class from the JavaFX library, and I need to write a method that checks it's current state, ie. if it's playing or not. I suppose I should use the getStatus() method, but that only gets me so far, as I can't figure out how I derive it's state from there. How can I use the getStatus() method to learn the MediaPlayer object's state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your hunch is correct and `MediaPlayer`'s `getStatus()` method provides you with the desired information. Check out it's extensive [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.Status.html).

Also there's a lot of event handlers for status change, e.g. `onPaused()`, `onReady()` for you to set up your custom callbacks.

Or, if I didn't get you correctly what is exactly you lack in `getStatus`'s output?

Comment: Well, my problem is that I can't figure out how to retrieve the status from the getStatus() method. I see it's return type is MediaPlayer.Status and I get it's a static field called PLAYING that I should somehow retrieve, but I can't figure out how. (I should underline that I'm an absolute novice)

Comment: I see so the thing is getStatus() returns you an enum value that represents the current status of your MediaPlayer, all possible statuses are listed in the javadoc I provided you with previously. You could use this value in order to, say, check status transition and make your app behave accordingly. For that you only need to track current state and register event handlers via on<Status-of-interest> methods.